# Behaviour of Prototype design in below code

Tags: c++, c++11

while I am learning Prototype design online, I got a code but it looks error from my side, can someone please check and confirm it

```
class Stooge {
public:
 virtual Stooge* clone() = 0;
 virtual void slap_stick() = 0;
};

class Curly : public Stooge {
public:
    Stooge*   clone() { return new Curly; }
    void slap_stick() {
      cout << "Curly: suffer abuse\n"; }
    };

    Stooge* Factory::s_prototypes[] = {
        0, new Larry, new Moe, new Curly
    };
    Stooge* Factory::make_stooge( int choice = 3 ) {
        return s_prototypes[choice]->clone();
    }
```

`make_stooge` in `Factory` creates two object or not? because

- `s_prototypes[choice]` returns one object and
- `s_prototypes[choice]->clone()` again returns another object.

Comment: `but it looks error from my side` What error? Btw, your `clone()` doesn't even clone, it just returns a new `Curly` object.

Comment: `s_prototype[choice]` doesn't create anything, it just returns a pointer to something that already exists.

Comment: clone should do something like: `Stooge*   clone() { return new Curly(*this); }` Prototype pattern is required rarely, mostly when creation of new instance is costlier than making a copy

Comment: @Swift In the case of `Curly`, those are both the same

Comment: @Caleth if the code we see is the ONLY code present in reality. The only use of prototype pattern is legal when it's not the case (Curly would have some resources and a copy c-tor). Otherwise whole expierence is akin to learning how to fart tunefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is declaration of an array (and probably it should be private)

```
 Stooge* Factory::s_prototypes[] = {
        nullptr, new Larry, new Moe, new Curly
    };
```

Note, that I replaced 0 with nullptr.
It is initialized with instances of objects.

clone() should make a copy of object. Which it doesn't in your case.  Instead of prototype you created a simple factory. it's not a necessary method in your particular case, because you may implement that as a copy constructor for `Curly` (Moe and Larry as well).

It is used when the type of objects to create is determined by a prototypical instance, which is cloned to produce new objects. This pattern is used to:

Prototype pattern is used to

- avoid subclasses of an object creator in the client application, like the factory method pattern does.
- avoid the inherent cost of creating a new object in the standard way (e.g., using the 'new' keyword) when it is prohibitively expensive for a given application.

In C++ usual content of `ConcreteProtoType::clone()` method would be

```
  return new ConcreteProtoType(*this);
```

Sometimes with some added code required to create new instance by architecture. (A call of initialization methods? new expression would be a placement new using memory pool? Some action we can't do in constructor, as a call to a virtual method?)

That requires definition of copy constructor if object cannot be shallow-copied (if it can be, why we use prototype?)

Answer (score 0):

It does not.

```
Stooge* Factory::s_prototypes[] = {
0, new Larry, new Moe, new Curly
};
```

This is your first object creation.

```
Stooge* Factory::make_stooge( int choice = 3 ) {
return s_prototypes[choice]->clone();
}
```

This function clones the existing object to return a new one. There's exactly one object being created here according to the example code.

Comment: s_prototypes[choice]0x2b07245ccc20
s_prototypes[choice]->clone()0x2b07245ceca0

Comment: While printing I got two different address